# How should I cite an executive order in a paper?

Tags: citation-style

I want to cite [this president action](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/07/09/executive-order-on-promoting-competition-in-the-american-economy/). How do I properly cite this source in a paper?  I cannot use Mendeley to cite directly, and in the papers’ cases, Mendeley did all the work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example using the [APA](https://libguides.umgc.edu/c.php?g=1003870&p=7423443) citation style:

> Exec. Order No. 14036, 86 Fed. Reg. 36987 (July 9, 2021).

The corresponding in-text citation is as follows:

> (Exec. Order No. 36987, 2021)

Federal Register numbers can be looked up [online](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2021/07/14/2021-15069/promoting-competition-in-the-american-economy).